# Как запускать потоки пачками по 100

Tags: python

Как запускать потоки пачками по 100, чтобы после завершения первой пачки, ишла вторая?

Comment: 1. запустить сто потоков. 2. дождаться их завершения. 3. перейти к шагу 1

Comment: как поместить жирафа в холодильник? открыть холодильник, положить туда жирафа, закрыть холодильник

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему так - сперва запускаю потоки, каждый раз когда запускается поток, я отслеживаю сколько их их уже запущено, если больше 100 я запускаю цикл while, в котором я отслеживаю сколько потоков активно, если активно меньше 5 (сделал так, чтобы если 1-3 потоки затупили, остальные чтобы их не ждали) я убиваю цикл. Работает чудесно!